# Adding different sized pages to PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a table and a chart to be added to a PDF Document. I have used the iTextSharpLibrary to add the contents to the PDF file.

Actually the problem is that the chart has a width of 1500px and the table fits in comfortably in an A4 page size.

Actually the chart image that I get must not be scaled to fit in the page as it reduces the viewability. Hence, I need to add a new page that has a wider width than the other ones or at least change the page orientation to landscape and then add the image. How do I do this?

This is the code that I used to add a new page and then resize the page and then add the image. This is not working. Any fixes?

```
var imageBytes = ImageGenerator.GetimageBytes(ImageSourceId);
var myImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageBytes);

document.NewPage();

document.SetPageSize(new Rectangle(myImage.Width, myImage.Height));

myImage.ScaleToFit(document.PageSize.Width, document.PageSize.Height);
document.Add(myImage);
```

Comment: "This is not working" means what? You get an error? Did you check the page size in your PDF viewer?

Comment: Do you want to keep the image size? In your question you say: "_Actually the chart image that i get must not be scaled to fit in the page..._", but in your code snippet you contradict this statement by calling `ScaleToFit()`.

Comment: @OcasoProtal: I don't get any error. But the page size is not changed to accomodate the chart

Comment: @kuujinbo: Even if i use `chartImage.ScaleAbsoluteHeight(document.PageSize.Height);
chartImage.ScaleAbsoluteWidth(document.PageSize.Width);`, no changes are made in the exported chart

Comment: I tried to change the pagesize via document.SetPageSize(new Rectangle(...)), but this seems to work before calling the PdfDocument.CreateInstance.

Comment: Found some class reference for iTextSharp: http://www.afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs-itextsharp/Index.html

Comment: @saravanan: We're not on the same page here. In your **question** you say that you **don't** want to scale the image, you **only** want to change the **page size** based on the **existing** image size. But you  keep bringing up calling one of the `Image` object methods to **scale/resize** the image. So I don't understand what you're trying to do. Update your question and maybe someone can help you. The link you gave for the documentation is nice, but it's for the **old** 4.1.6 version, which is over **two** years old.

Comment: I fixed the Issue. I have to set the page size before calling the GetInstance of the Pdfdocument. Then, i can give different pagesizes for each page.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the Issue. I have to set the page size before calling the GetInstance of the Pdfdocument. Then, i can give different pagesizes for each page

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by `before calling the GetInstance of the Pdfdocument`, but setting the pageSize right before calling newPage works.
Here follows the c# code to create a new pdf that's made of two pictures, no matter how wild their sizes difference is. The important lines here are the `new Document` and `SetPageSize` ones.

```
static public void MakePdfFrom2Pictures (String pic1InPath, String pic2InPath, String pdfOutPath)
{
    using (FileStream pic1In = new FileStream (pic1InPath, FileMode.Open))
    using (FileStream pic2In = new FileStream (pic2InPath, FileMode.Open))
    using (FileStream pdfOut = new FileStream (pdfOutPath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        //Load first picture
        Image image1 = Image.GetInstance (pic1In);
        //I set the position in the image, not during the AddImage call
        image1.SetAbsolutePosition (0, 0);
        //Load second picture
        Image image2 = Image.GetInstance (pic2In);
        // ...
        image2.SetAbsolutePosition (0, 0);
        //Create a document whose first page has image1's size.
        //Image IS a Rectangle, no need for new Rectangle (Image.Width, Image.Height).
        Document document = new Document (image1);
        //Assign writer
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance (document, pdfOut);
        //Allow writing
        document.Open ();
        //Get writing head
        PdfContentByte pdfcb = writer.DirectContent;
        //Put the first image on the first page
        pdfcb.AddImage (image1);
        //The new page will have image2's size
        document.SetPageSize (image2);
        //Add the new second page, and start writing in it
        document.NewPage ();
        //Put the second image on the second page
        pdfcb.AddImage (image2);
        //Finish the writing
        document.Close ();
    }
}
```